# Why doesn't kprobe work on Centos 7 kernel 4.16.6?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, trace

I'm on CentOS 7 (Linux 4.16.6)

```
root@host # uname -r
4.16.6-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
```

Following the [document](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/trace/kprobetrace.html#usage-examples), I add a kprobe to trace `sys_clone`:

```
root@host # grep sys_clone /proc/kallsyms
ffffffff81084c70 T sys_clone
root@host # echo 'p:testprobe sys_clone' >/sys/kernel/tracing/kprobe_events
root@host # cat /sys/kernel/tracing/kprobe_events
p:kprobes/testprobe sys_clone
root@host # cat /sys/kernel/tracing/events/kprobes/testprobe/id
1874
```

Now if I enable it and then trigger it by running whatever commands in another terminal, `trace_pipe` does not contain any data:

```
root@host # echo 1 > /sys/kernel/tracing/events/kprobes/testprobe/enable
root@host # cat /sys/kernel/tracing/tracing_on
1
root@host # cat /sys/kernel/tracing/events/kprobes/testprobe/enable
1
root@host # cat /sys/kernel/tracing/events/kprobes/enable
1
root@host # cat /sys/kernel/tracing/trace_pipe
^C   <-- it blocks here
```

The kernel configuration looks fine:

```
root@host # grep KPROBE /boot/config-4.16.6-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
CONFIG_KPROBES=y
CONFIG_KPROBES_ON_FTRACE=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KPROBES=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KPROBES_ON_FTRACE=y
CONFIG_KPROBE_EVENTS=y
# CONFIG_BPF_KPROBE_OVERRIDE is not set
```

What could be the possible cause of kprobes not working?

Comment: Try running [kprobe](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/kernel/kprobe), for example `sudo bash kprobe 'p:myopen do_sys_open filename=+0(%si):string'`